How to move Oracle database backup from Dell Datadomain to cloud storage (e.g. S3) using Veeam
I have a number of huge Oracle databases and the backup of these database have been sending to DataDomain (using RMAN and DD as VTL), and I would like to move those Oracle database backup to cloud storage e.g. AWS S3, using Veeam.
Can someone advise the high level approach? How I need to restore every single Oracle backup to a temporary Oracle instance and backup again with Veeam Plug-in for Oracle RMAN in order to move the backup to cloud?
